# disqus comments refreshing takes really long

Tags: comments, disqus

I added disqus to my site (on localhost) and when I add comments it doesn't refresh automatically, it takes a really long time. About 10-15 minutes. I already turned developer mode on, and it is working because it reads the amount of comments, only it takes ages to read them. So when there are 5 comments, and I add 10 more it will stay on 5 for about 15 minutes. Is there something I can do about that?

Answer (score 0):

The comments are cached, so no it's not something you can control. Realtime is still immediate, so that's generally how new comments get delivered to the client.

However, I wouldn't necessarily count on it being that way forever. We do change things to better the user experience based on feedback, whenever possible.